# Grep: omit spaces between search and results

Tags: regex, grep

Source text file is:  `Gross Bushels 1225.35`

Grep is:              `(?<=Bushels\s)[\0-9,\.]*.`

Desired return is:            `1225.35`

I am searching for `"Gross Bushels"` and want to capture the number directly after that, minus any spaces.

However, the source file may have more than one space between the `"s"` and the first number. I want to truncate 1 or more spaces, not just one. I understand I probably need some switch on the `"\s"` but cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\K` to reset a match in PCRE which allows you to avoid lookbehind which cannot be of dynamic length. You may use this:

```
s='Gross Bushels   1225.35'
grep -oP '\bBushels\s+\K[\d,.]+' <<< "$s"
```

```
1225.35
```

If you want your regex to be a bit more strict then use:

```
\bBushels\h+\K\d+([.,]\d+)*
```

Comment: Your first answer worked perfectly. It always returns 1225.35, with an arbitrary number of spaces between "Gross Bushel"s and the number. Thank you.